# Custom AutoCompleteTextView is not working is android version 6.0.1, but its work properly on older versions

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

Custom autocompletetextview is not working in android version 6.0.1, buts its work properly on older versions. If any code changes are need for custom autocompletetextview in latest android version 6.0.1 or above.

Comment: can you elaborate what do you mean by not working ?

Comment: `AutoCompleteTextView` is working in 6.0.1 or above too, what do you have problems with?

Comment: Auto suggestion is not shown, while typing the first characters